# How to use a 'reverse trigger' in KEDA where the ScaledObject stops scaling up?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks, keda

I am using Prometheus as a trigger type for KEDA in my Kubernetes cluster. Right now I added a trigger that scales up pods based on CPU usage. But I also want to add a trigger that forces KEDA to only create 30 pods per node.

The reason is that when KEDA wants to scale up and there are pods created in a 'PENDING' state, waiting for the new node to start, it creates much more than are actually needed. This is because I can't figure out how Prometheus can see the amount of Pending pods present.

is very nice thank you